# Arctis 7 Steel Series headphones balance sound

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, headphones

So I bought the *SteelSeries Arctis 7* headphones but the sound is not balanced, the left side is slightly louder than the right side.

For some reason I can not find a way to balance them in Windows 10. I think its because they are wireless using analogue and not Bluetooth. I have tried to go into playback but the balance button does not show up.

Does anyone know a way to balance this kind of headphones?

Comment: If they are connected wirelessly then they have to be connected over Bluetooth.

Comment: no they can be connected through analogue :) not every wireless headset is bluetooth

Comment: Seems to be the same problem：https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/TxEQXV46AMQXPD  https://www.reddit.com/r/steelseries/comments/abbgt2/how_to_balance_left_right_volume_arctis_7